# Unable to extract values linked to data points from an interactive line chart

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, web, charts, interactive

I am trying to extract the percentage values (Target Rate Probability) from an interactive chart with preselected conditions "13 Dez23" and "Historical" on the following website: https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/cme-fedwatch-tool.html?redirect=/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html. The percentage probabilities only appear when I hover over the respective data points with a mouse.

**I have tried the following:**

```
XPath of tried element: /html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[5]/g[2]/path[2]
```

**1. Method Approach:** Webdriverwait in order for the elements to load on the page

**1. Method Error:** TimeoutException

**2. Method Approach:**

```
driver.execute_script("document.evaluate('/html/body
/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[5]/g[2]/path[2]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.style.display = 'block';")
```

**2. Method Error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

**3. Method Approach:**

```
driver.execute_script("document.evaluate('/html/body/form
/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[5]/g[2]/path[2]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.style.visibility = 'visible';")
```

**3. Method Error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

EC: Invisibility of element is True

**Code: **

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import datetime as dt
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/cme-fedwatch-tool.html?redirect=/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html')
time.sleep(10)
page_source=driver.page_source
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame('cmeIframe-jtxelq2f')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[8]/a").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedFedWatchTool_lbHistorical").click()
time.sleep(10)

# 175-200 target rate probability
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
CSS_Selector = '#highcharts-986wlrn-17 > svg > g.highcharts-series-group > g.highcharts-markers.highcharts-series-0.highcharts-line-series.highcharts-color-0.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-halo.highcharts-color-0'

# Wait for the element
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Check, if the element is invisible (IT IS)
print(wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, CSS_Selector))))

#Change the data-z-index', '4' to put infront of the other elements (DOESNT WORK!)
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('#highcharts-986wlrn-17 > svg > g.highcharts-series-group > g.highcharts-markers.highcharts-series-0.highcharts-line-series.highcharts-color-0.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-halo.highcharts-color-0').setAttribute('data-z-index', '4')")

time.sleep(10)

#Doesnt find the first element of 175-200 (DOESNT WORK!)
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#highcharts-986wlrn-17 > svg > g.highcharts-series-group > g.highcharts-markers.highcharts-series-0.highcharts-line-series.highcharts-color-0.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-halo.highcharts-color-0')

# Move the mouse over the very left element first element 175-200 (DOESNT WORK!)
action.move_to_element(element)
action.perform()

#Determining the location and size in order for the mouse to move along the interactive chart for 175-200
loc = element.location
size = element.size

#moving to right end of the interactive chart for 175-200 (DOESNT WORK!)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(element,510, 0).perform() #found 510 when inspecting the chart metrics

#first date (found on the very left of the chart) (DOESNT WORK!)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[10]/g/text/tspan[1]')

#first value (found on the very left of the chart) (DOESNT WORK!)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/svg/g[5]/g[2]/path[1]')

#setting the limit of when to break out of the while loop (DOESNT WORK!)
limit = dt.datetime.strptime('Thu, May  5, 2022', '%a, %B %-m, %B')
pace = -5

dictionary = {}

while True:
    #moving back to the very left first element of the interactive chart
    action.move_by_offset(pace, 0).perform() # moving by a pace of -5 (-5 is trial value)
    date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#highcharts-986wlrn-17 > svg > g.highcharts-tooltip > g.highcharts-label.highcharts-tooltip-header.highcharts-tooltip-box > text').text
    value = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#highcharts-986wlrn-17 > svg > g.highcharts-tooltip > g.highcharts-label.highcharts-tooltip-box.highcharts-color-0 > text').text

    if dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%a, %B %-m, %B') < limit:
        break
    # add results to dictionary
    if date in dictionary:
        pass
    else:
        dictionary[date] = value

driver.quit()

[![Interactive Line Chart][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDHQt.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that you already clicked on "13 Dec23" and "Historical":

```
import time
import pyautogui # pip install pyautogui

# sleep 3 seconds so that you can switch to the browser and move the mouse to the start position
time.sleep(3)

# start position: put mouse on chart's left border, for example between 0% and 20%
start_pos = pyautogui.position()

# this works only if the tooltip containing the percentage values was already been displayed once
old_values = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'g.highcharts-tooltip').text.replace('\n','').split('●')
data = []
for k in range(500):
    pyautogui.moveTo(start_pos.x + 3*k , start_pos.y)
    new_values = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'g.highcharts-tooltip').text.replace('\n','').split('●')
    if new_values != old_values:
        old_values = new_values
        data.append(new_values)
    # uncomment this if you want the mouse to move slower
    # time.sleep(.1)
```

`data` will then be a list of lists, where each list contains the day label and the corresponding percentage values (as strings)

```
[['Thu, May 5, 2022',
  '350-375: 17.18%',
  '325-350: 28.11%',
  '300-325: 27.01%',
  '250-275: 4.39%',
  '275-300: 14.80%',
  '225-250: 0.65%',
  '375-400: 6.27%',
  '400-425: 1.36%',
  '425-450: 0.17%'],
 ['Fri, May 6, 2022',
  '350-375: 15.54%',
  '325-350: 26.14%',
  '300-325: 26.94%',
  '250-275: 6.08%',
  '275-300: 16.73%',
  '225-250: 1.24%',
  '375-400: 5.71%',
  '400-425: 1.29%',
  '425-450: 0.17%',
  '200-225: 0.14%'],
  ... etc ...
```

Comment: the following error happend: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".highcharts-tooltip"}. Check the image below for the values I want to extract.

Comment: @linusotte You get that error because the object with class `highcharts-tooltip` is not created automatically when the page loads, but it is created the first time that you manually hover the mouse over the chart. What image are you talking about? I don't see any

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDHQt.jpg. I want the percentage values in the upper left corner(0,65%, 4,39% etc). Do you know how?

Comment: @linusotte Unfortunately, only the percentage values corresponding to the currently selected point of the chart are found in the html. So you have to loop over the horizontal points of the chart (i.e. move the mouse with selenium), and for each point extract the percentage values

Comment: @linusotte First you have to try to do the job by yourself using tutorials, then if you reach a point where you are stuck at, you post your code here and we will try to help

Comment: I updated my code and still doesnt work. I added comments to my code for understanding purposes. I am stuck "#Change the data-z-index', '4'" comment I left in the code. If you could help me, I would be really thankful :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: @linusotte Nice job, but why you don't go to Downloads and just download the csv file "13 dic 2023" with all the percentage values?

Comment: You are very right, but I want to apply my learned knowledge to a practical case. I really want this code to work :)

Comment: Could you help me getting the code to work?

Comment: @linusotte i will try soon

Comment: I genuinely appreciate your help and looked through the code again and tried it out myself and it worked perfectly. I just have one question: for the css selector you used „g.highcharts-tooltip„ which isn’t the full css selector. Why did you do that, so that I can understand for the future?

Comment: @linusotte If the webelement has an unique class or id, you can find it using that unique attribute instead of the full selector. Try opening the browser inspector, then press CTRL+F and paste `g.highcharts-tooltip`, you will see that there is only 1 result, hence that attribute uniquely identify the chart tooltip. You can verify this in python too, run `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'g.highcharts-tooltip')` (notice `find_elements` instead of `find_element`) and you will see that it returns a list with only 1 element